# SSL: Can't find the certificate "" and its private key in the Keychain

Tags: git, keychain

I get the following error when trying to clone from github over https.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<any-github-repo>.git/': SSL: Can't find the
certificate "" and its private key in the Keychain.
```

git+ssh does continue to work but for some cases I need to be able to use https, like when running `brew update` for example.

I have where the certificate is simply `""`. Every other example I have at least specifies which certificate it is looking for which helps to deduce where the problem lies.

Does anyone know what certificate `""` might be? Or how best to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the root of the problem. I have a github config file at `~/.gitconfig`

In there I found this line

```
[http]
    sslCert =
    sslVerify = false
```

`sslCert =` is where `""` was being defined. I've removed the `[http]` section and it now works.